# Error in generating csv in php

Tags: php, export-to-csv

i am generating CSV,the file is generated very fine but i have problem in data in excel sheet.
i have phone number,time  column.in browser its quite well but in csv file its not.

```
one row in browser= Unknown,03224250040,"2012-03-18 15:06:33",0,Outgoing
in csv file =       Unknown 3.22E+09     ##########          0  Outgoing
```

but when i click on this 3.22E+09 in my csv it turns to this 03224250040 same for cell ####.
how can i add my column names too ??

this is my code

```
 header("Content-type: text/csv");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");

     function outputCSV($data) {
            $outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");
            function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
           fputcsv($filehandler, $vals); 
           }
          array_walk($data, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
        fclose($outstream);
        }    

       outputCSV($array);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // Write column names
   $result = mysql_query("show columns from $table",$conn);
   for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
     $colArray[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   $fieldArray[$i] = $colArray[$i]['Field'];
   }
    fputcsv($file,$fieldArray);
```